# Knockout option select reinitializes after hiding/showing

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

When using the select with knockouts 'option' binding, I see behaviour I wasn't expecting when hiding the select element and showing it again.

When I select an option in the list the observable is given the right value. However, when I hide the select html item and then again make it visible, the value selected before will be lost.

For my test I'm using the following html template:

```
Visible: <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: visible" />
<!-- ko 'if': visible -->
<select data-bind="options: options, optionsText: 'name', value: selectedItem"></select>
<!-- /ko -->
```

in combination with

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.visible = ko.observable(true);
    this.options = ko.observableArray([
    {name: 'A', value: 'A00'},
    {name: 'B', value: 'A01'},
    {name: 'C', value: 'A02'},
    ]);

        this.selectedItem = ko.computed({
      read: function () {
        console.log("reading value");
      },
      write: function (newSelection) {
        console.log("setting value:" + newSelection.value);
      }
     });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

You can test this in my example on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5wZQ2/169/

When you select a value (B for example in the list), the observable gets the value. When you uncheck visible and hide the selection box and then make it visible again, it will have lost his selected value and be reinitialized to the first item in the list.

Can anybody explain this behaviour?

Comment: Is there a particular reason, you need a writable Computed Observable Property? Also, in the `read` function inside computed observable you are not returning any value, so nothing would be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are binding the select to a computed which lacks a backing field there is no way for the UI to save its state. Normally you would have an observable store the currently selected value, and the computed would only be used to perform some transformation on the data in-between the backing field and the UI.

If you add an observable, and pass its value through the computed then the select will save its state and re-bind to the last value after being removed and re-added via the 'if' binding because it will be re-initialized with the observable's saved value.

```
 this._selectedItem = ko.observable();

 this.selectedItem = ko.computed({
     read: function () {
         console.log("reading value");
         return this._selectedItem();
     },
     write: function (newSelection) {
         console.log("setting value:" + newSelection.value);
         this._selectedItem(newSelection);
     }
 }, this);
```

In your example there isn't actually a reason to use a computed at all. You can bind the select to a plain observable instead.

```
this.selectedItem = ko.observable();
```

Then if you still wish to log changes to the console you can use the subscribe method on the observable.

```
this.selectedItem.subscribe(function(newSelection){
    console.log("setting value:" + newValue);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that I wanted to perform some changes based on the new value of the select. This should however only happen when the user modifies the selected value, not because it is being loaded in the dom. Using a second observable wouldn't really fix that issue since we still don't know what caused the new value to be set.

Comment: Did you try adding the observable? What about my first example didn't work as you needed? If you bind to the computed but initial load using the observable you should only get notified on user modifications as you stated.

Comment: The entire point of using a computed is to use them in conjunction with another observable. per the knockout documentation: "these are functions that are dependent on one or more other observables, and will automatically update whenever any of these dependencies change."

Comment: The reason you might get a an initial "setting value: A01" in your console is because your select is set up to force an initial value, so the element forces an update to your computed. If you give it an initial value instead of forcing the element to choose one you won't see that behavior. Here's even a fiddle to prove that it works https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/7Lyxpjdb/

Comment: You were absolutely right, your solution worked as you explained. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

the expected behavior happens if you change the if binding to a visible binding. see your updated fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/5wZQ2/171/

```
Visible: <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: visible" />
<div data-bind="visible: visible">
<select data-bind="options: options, optionsText: 'name', value: selectedItem"></select>
</div>
```

I believe the difference is explained in the documentation http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html which states

> if plays a similar role to the visible binding. The difference is
>   that, with visible, the contained markup always remains in the DOM and
>   always has its data-bind attributes applied - the visible binding just
>   uses CSS to toggle the container element’s visiblity. The if binding,
>   however, physically adds or removes the contained markup in your DOM,
>   and only applies bindings to descendants if the expression is true.